# Ti.Network.TCPSocket not returning anything

Tags: tidesdk

I am trying to use Ti.Network.TCPSocket to login to an IMAP server.

Its hard as I am not receiving anything back to debug with. For example:

```
var socket = Ti.Network.createTCPSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
socket.connect();
socket.write("LOGIN user pass\r\n");

//event handlers
socket.onWrite(function(data) {
      Ti.API.debug('Written to socket: '+data);
});

socket.onError(function(data) {
      Ti.API.debug(data);
});
```

I am not getting anything back. Not even an error or some sort of code or acknowledgement that something is actually happening.

Am I doing something wrong here?

How can I get these even handlers to work or the socket to return some sort of message.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE - Full Code**

```
Ti.API.debug('Start A socket Connection');
var socket = Ti.Network.createTCPSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);

Ti.API.debug('Connect the socket');
socket.connect();

Ti.API.debug('Socket Connected');
var command = uniqueid()+" LOGIN USER PASS\r\n";
socket.write(command);

//this is where the debug stops. No echo.
Ti.API.debug('Command Run');

socket.onWrite(function(data) {
    Ti.API.debug('Written to socket: '+data);
});

socket.onError(function(data) {
    Ti.API.debug('Error: '+data);
});

socket.onReadComplete(function(data) {
    Ti.API.debug('Here: '+data);
});

function uniqueid() {
    var s = [];
    var hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s[i] = hexDigits.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10), 1);
    }
    s[14] = "4";
    s[19] = hexDigits.substr((s[19] & 0x3) | 0x8, 1);
    s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23];

    var uuid = s.join("");
    return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 993 is for IMAP over SSL.

Comment: I am able to do it with PHP fine, why not the TCP network function? Why can't I see anything returned?

Comment: You can't see anything returned because the server is waiting for you to negotiate an SSL connection. You have no code to do that. (And even if you did, you still wouldn't get a response to your command because it's not in accord with the [IMAP protocol](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt), section 2.2, which says *all interactions transmitted by client and server are in the form of lines; that is, strings that end with a CRLF*.)

Comment: I can make a connection via PHP in the same testing environment. Such as `$fp = fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com', '993', $errno, $errstr, 15);` Which works great. Why would this be any different?

Comment: @SolidPink: For exactly the reason I've said twice now -- port 993 is for IMAP over SSL. If you connect to it over SSL, it will work (at least, it will once you follow the IMAP protocol and send *lines*). If you don't, it won't.

Comment: Yes I am writing a proper command, with a unique tag for each line ending with a CRLF. Like I said, I have no problem connecting and running commands in PHP. Why can't I get the same thing to run in TideSDK?

Comment: Please show me where in the code that doesn't work is the code to negotiate an SSL connection. If you can't, and you can't, then that's your answer. (And where is the code to send a CRLF?)

Comment: Thanks for you help with this. The CRLF is the normal carriage return. "\r\n"

Comment: Now you got the CRLF, but you're still missing SSL.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you need to make connections over SSL, use something that supports SSL to make those connections.

Comment: So are you saying the TideSDK can't support SSL with their TCP connections? If so, that would have been nice to know at the start.

Comment: @SolidPink: It does not to my knowledge. But if it did, you'd certainly have to *tell* it to use SSL somehow.

Comment: Hmmm nothing in the docs. I've already checked. But then again it doesn't do anything on port 143 either. Not even a BAD return.

Answer (score 0):

- onWrite doesn't exist - thats a bug, and probably why your debug statements stop.
- try moving your socket.connect() to after you define the handlers.
- Use an interval, and socket.isClosed() before trying to write to the socket. Once you get a socket.isClosed() == false, then go ahead. Once you have the socket, you can play with it in the webinspector console in app as well.

This won't solve all your problems, but may help. You might want to try using a utility like wireshark to see what exactly you are sending down the wire when you socket.write, and compare that with what your email client sends.